# Firediff load snapshot

Tags: html, firefox-addon

I was wondering if it is possible to load a snapshot of edits made to the HTML and CSS of a page in firebug with firediff.

Example: My job requires me to be constantly changing windows and I accidentally close the firefox window I'm working with from time to time. I was wondering if it was possible to, when I reload the page I was working on, the changes I had made previously could automatically be loaded to save time and effort (automatically if possible).

Note: I'm working on a system that does NOT have access to the server (I make/suggest changes, submit them and then they are implemented by others) so the changes would have to be saved and loaded locally.